# How to use Lilypond with Sublime

Tags: sublime-text, music, lilypond

It would seem I'm forever a LaTeX novice: I cant get my head around the instructions on how to invoke `lilypond-book`. According to [lilypond's documentation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.12/Documentation/user/lilypond-program/Invoking-lilypond_002dbook#Invoking-lilypond_002dbook) you have to use this:

```
lilypond-book --pdf yourfile.pdftex
pdflatex yourfile.tex
```

But I'm not a clever man... I'm using Sublime Text 3 and `LaTeXing`, using mostly `lualatex`. I would assume one have to put this in the quick build settings in one way or another, but I do not know how.

```json
"quick_build": [
    {
        "name": "Primary Quick Build: pdflatex",
        "primary": true,
        "cmds": ["pdflatex"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Quick Build 1: pdflatex + bibtex + pdflatex (2x)",
        "cmds": ["pdflatex", "bibtex", "pdflatex", "pdflatex"]
    },
    {
        "name": "Quick Build 2: pdflatex + biber + pdflatex (2x)",
        "cmds": ["pdflatex", "biber", "pdflatex", "pdflatex"]
    }
],
```

Answer (score 4):

This is only a partial answer, because I don't have Sublime Text. But it may help to understand the lilypond-book process better in case you don't. As far as I understand it, with lilypond-book,

- You write a LaTeX file that includes Lilypond syntax inside a `lilypond` environment. You name this file `file.lytex`.
- When you run lilypond-book on that file, the lilypond-book program does two things:

  1. it extracts the lilypond parts and compiles them into separate cropped PDFs, and
  2. it writes a new LaTeX file (called `file.tex`) that includes your LaTeX content and replaces the lilypond code with `\includegraphics` instructions to include the PDF score images it created from your code.

So you run lilypond-book on the `.lytex` file, and then you run pdflatex (or lualatex or xelatex) on the `.tex` file that lilypond-book produces. If you are automating this workflow through the editor, makefile program, or shell script, remember that the latex engine must compile not your original file but the .tex file produced by lilypond-book.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. It is not that obvious choice of procedure anymore, i mean, doing it manually (make the notation i lilypond/sibelius/finale) and just adding it would take less time then doing like this. Will digg deeper.

Comment: I agree absolutely. I make the scores in separate files (I crop them using a bash script on my github page, https://github.com/andrewacashner/lilycrop) and then include them in the score manually. I make all the scores equal to the \textwidth, and then I use an \includescore macro for \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{#1}.

Comment: How do you use your bash program? Is it lilypond only or does it work with other formats as well? Asking because i hardly know what bash is.

Comment: Sorry, the correct URL is https://github.com/andrewacashner/lilypond.